# Jdeveloper war deployment to tomcat

Tags: tomcat6, jdeveloper

I am a newbie.

I am trying to publish procedures which return refcursor as webservice. 
As webservices do not support ref cursor return type so I chnaged the return type to pl/sql table.

I created the jax rpc in Jdeveloper studio 11.1.2.4.0 and tested it. This runs ok. I need to deploy it on tomcat server and am failing completely.

I copied the war file generated by Jdeveloper to the webapps directory in Tomcat and started Tomcat but this didn't work, as the following exception was thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: omsdevconn.MyWebServicetomcatUser cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

If someone has done it then can I get the steps for the process to deploy it on Tomcat 6.0.37?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Download jaxws-rt-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and jaxws-2_0.jar
Copy into $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder

Add the following in web.xml under web-app

```
<web-app>  
**<listener>  
<listener-class>  
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener  
</listener-class>  
</listener>**  
............<!--your other servlet definations-->
</web-app>
```

create sun-jaxws.xml under your applications web-inf folder and configure endpoints.You can have a look at jdeveloper generated xml file to get all the information

sample sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"version="2.0">
<endpoint name="fromwsdl"
interface="com.foo.yourserviceInterface"
implementation="com.foo.yourserviceClass"
wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdl/youservice.wsdl"
service="YourService"
port="YourServicePort"
url-pattern="/serviceAccessUrl" />
</endpoints>
```

create war for your application and deploy you application under tomcat/webapps
start tomcat

After starting tomcat you can access the service as
http:/host:port/yourservicename/methodInService

**As you are calling oracle plsql code and IF you are using any oracle specific calls like OracleCallabelStatement then on run time you will get class cast exceptions from tomcat datasource when trying to cast callabelstatement to oraclecallabelstatement for that you need to configure oracledatasource in tomcat**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/ucp-jdbc-tomcat-355431.html

More information on Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS)

https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/UsersGuide.html#1.0_Introduction

Comment: You should not provide only a link, please explain the solution in short words.

Comment: Edited the entry and posted the steps

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deploy service generated by Jdeveloper when **exposing a plsql procedure as webservice**

***I am not allowed to post more that 2 links so please add and extra "/" after http: to correct the links***

***This solution uses Apache Axis which allows you to call your web service(which is not exposed as restful) directly from browser by creating a SOAP request behind the scenes and involke the service method giving it soap message.***

1)Generate a webservice in Jdeveloper .It will create java files and corresponding ".class" file , "wsdl file" in web-inf and some other xml files. Make a note of LOCATION of .class file and wsdl file.

2)Download eclipse and extract it on your hard drive (It needs java to run So you must have java installed on system .You can download eclipse from 
http:/www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

3)Download Axis plugin for eclipse from here :
http:/www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.2/axis2-eclipse-service-plugin-1.6.2.zip
and install it in eclipse. Installation Instructions :
http:/axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html

4)Generate the aar file via eclipse axis plugin. Instructions :
http:/axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/servicearchiver-plugin.html#Operation

5)Make following changes in tomcat-user.xml file

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>  
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-jmx"/>
```

6)**IF YOU ARE USING ORACLE SPECIFIC CLASSES IN CODE (Which most probably Jdeveloper will produce)** : Configure a oracle data source in tomcat (server.xml or context.xml). Instructions :
http:/www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/ucp-jdbc-tomcat-355431.html
**Make sure you have ojdbc6.jar and ucp.jar in Tomcat/lib folder.**

7)Download axis war file to deploy in tomcat from here :
http:/www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.2/axis2-eclipse-service-plugin-1.6.2.zip

Unzip the zip , it will have a axis2.war file in it. Put this war file under “\Tomcat\webapps” directory

8)Start tomcat. On tomcat console see if there are any errors in deploying axis. If everything is fine you should be able to see axis page on http:/yourhost:yourport/axis2/

9)Click on Administration link . Enter user id “admin” and password “Axis2” and login

10)Click upload and browse to the location of aar file you generate in step 4 and upload. After it shows you success click on Available service. It takes a bit of time but you should be able to see you service.Click on service to see wsdl to verify

11)Call your service method from browser and cross your fingers and toes.
Note that the link to hit will be something Like

http:/yourhost:yourport/**axis2/services**/*YourServiceName/serviceMethod*?arg1=blah&

Make sure your got the arg names right.you should be able to see the correct names from wsdl